# Creating a xhtml table with javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table, xhtml

*Solved it by changing createElement to createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',tagname)*

I'm trying to add a table to my xhtml site with javascript, but after the adding-function is finished, the content of the table is just displayed as one line of text and not as a table. I tried the function in a html site and it works fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>

            <title>Title</title>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.onload = function () {

                var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
                var tabelle = document.createElement('table');
                tabelle.border = 1;
                var tblB = document.createElement('tbody');

                tabelle.appendChild(tblB)

                for(var i = 0; !(i>=10); i++){
                var tr = document.createElement('tr');
                tblB.appendChild(tr);

                for(var j = 0; !(j >= 10) ;j++){
                var td = document.createElement('td');
                var text = document.createTextNode("test");
                td.appendChild(text);
                tr.appendChild(td);

                }


                }
                body.appendChild(tabelle);
                alert(tabelle.innerHTML);

                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>test</h1>

        </body>
</html>
```

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Fhtf.png)

Comment: `for(var i = 0; !(i>=10); i++){` who thought you to use conditions like this? `i < 10` would be a lot more clear.

Comment: yeah I had it like that, but then i got an error with "not well formed"

Comment: @NarakLasak - Put your JavaScript in a CDATA block to avoid that "not well formed" error.

Comment: Off topic, but you can shorten `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]` to `document.body`.